# Number of ways to fill a 2xN grid with M colors

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, permutations, bipartite-matching

This question was asked in the onsite regionals for ACM ICPC 2013 at Amritapuri.
In short, the question asked to find the number of ways to fill a $ 2\times N$ grid with $M$ colors such that no two cells with the same row or same column have the same color.

The limits given are $1 \leq N$, and $M \leq 1000$ with 1000 test cases per input.

Based on the constraints the approach that comes to my mind after a long struggle includes having a precomputed DP table which can be used for every test case. I tried to apply the inclusion-exclusion principle but could not come up with any solution. I also tried to solve it using bipartite perfect matchings, but no success. How should I approach this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use inclusion-exclusion. There are $M!/(M-N)!$ choices for the first row. Fix these choices. The number of choices for the second row in which $T$ specific columns are bad (but the row itself is good) is $(M-T)!/(M-N)!$. According to the inclusion-exclusion principle, the required number is
$$ \frac{M!}{(M-N)!} \sum_{T=0}^N (-1)^T \binom{N}{T} \frac{(M-T)!}{(M-N)!}. $$
I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: Can you please  elaborate on `T specific columns are bad (but the row itself is good)` ?

Comment: A row is good if all colors are different. A column is bad if the colors are the same. You should be able to understand the rest if you understand the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler way to solve your problem, but just for fun, I'll outline a different approach that generalizes nicely. For a real-world implementation, the advantages should also be clear.

You can cast this problem, and similar problems like Sudoku as [constraint satisfaction problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem). After modeling the problem, you can feed it to a state-of-the-art solver such as [MINION](http://minion.sourceforge.net/) that does the dirty work for you. MINION can handle finding a single solution, as well as counting all the solutions to a problem.

In what follows, I'll present a short input file to MINION to solve an $2 \times M$ instance of your problem, where $M=3$.

```
MINION 3

**VARIABLES**
DISCRETE q[3] {0..2}
DISCRETE r[3] {0..2}

**CONSTRAINTS**
alldiff(q)
alldiff(r)
diseq(q[0],r[0])
diseq(q[1],r[1])
diseq(q[2],r[2])

**EOF**
```

There is a variable corresponding to every vertex in the grid graph, the other side of the graph is modeled by the array $q$, and the other one with $r$, if you will. Each one takes a value from the domain $0..M$, where $M=3$ in this example. The constraints ensure that vertices in a row must be colored with different colors, and that opposite vertices (meaning the two vertices in a column) receive different colors.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem statement says you want to find one example of a solution.  If that is really correct, here is a very simple way to find one solution.

- If $M < N$, there is no solution.  (Proof: consider how you're going to fill in the top row.  You're screwed no matter what you do.)
- If $M=N$, it is easy solution.  Fill in the top row with any permutation of the $M$ colors.  You can make the second row the same as the first row, but shifted over by one place.  That will satisfy all the constraints.
- If $M>N$, then throw away $M-N$ of the colors (your solution won't use them) and fill in the grid using just the first $M$ colors, using the method of the previous case.